# TypeError: cannot perform __sub__ with this index type: <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a sample code about adult census data.
When I run this segment of code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(encoded_data[encoded_data.columns - ["Target"]], encoded_data["Target"], train_size=0.70, random_state = 42)
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
X_train = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(X_train.astype("f64")), columns=X_train.columns)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test.astype("f64"))
```

I keep getting this error :

```
  2101     def __sub__(self, other):
   2102         raise TypeError("cannot perform __sub__ with this index type: "
-> 2103                         "{typ}".format(typ=type(self)))
   2104 
   2105     def __and__(self, other):

TypeError: cannot perform __sub__ with this index type: <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>
```

I'm currently using anaconda python27

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test.astype("float64"))
```